# Get to bunch of post IDs the latest comment respectively in MongoDB in one query

Tags: mongodb

I have an array of post Ids. Comments to posts are a collection on it's own and not embedded. Now I want to retrieve the latest comment to each post ID ideally in one query. `post_id` is a field in each comment document and a `timestamp` of course.

Post:

```
{
  _id: 123
}
```

Comment:

```
{
  _id: 567,
  post_id: 123,
  timestamp: 1498117182
}
```

Comment: it's not very clear. Please add sample documents from your collection, and the expected ouput

Comment: I think its quite clear what he wants. @OP AFAIK it is impossible to query multiple collections in 1 query (like a join) in mongodb. So you would have to do it in 2 queries. I recommend looking at projections with `$slice` to get the last element of the comments array and then use a normal find on the comments

Comment: @p.streef you can query multiple collection and perform join in mongodb (if the two collection have a field in common of course ) using **`$lookup`**

Comment: Well ok then! That means you should be able to use a $match,$project,$lookup aggregation pipeline to get what you need. I am assuming here you push the comments onto the back of the queue and the last is also the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comment has the post id it is a little simpler than my initial idea. first you get all the comments in your postId array. order the comments by timestamp (latest first) then group then by postId and use the first value for your fields

```
db.getCollection('comments').aggregate([
    {$match: {
        post_id: {$in : idArray}
        }},
    {$sort:{ timestamp : -1 }}, 
    {$group:{
        _id :  post_id,
        timestamp: { $first: "$timestamp" },
        comment_id: { $first: "$_id" }
        }}

]);
```

Comment: In the $group section, shouldn't it be `_id: "$post_id"`?

Comment: You are correct. I did not completely check the syntax